# View not translating across to LINQ properly

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, linq

Experiencing a real bizarre problem with ASP .Net (MVC Unity Framework). I have a view as follows (have simplified it in this example):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_eSummary] AS
SELECT a.ID,
a.Domain
FROM [Table1] a
GROUP BY a.ID,
a.Domain
```

The underlying table has repeated values so grouping to get distinct values.

In .Net, I have the following LINQ query:

```
var eSummary = from s in ctx.V_eSummary
                              select s;
```

Instead of seeing (as it shows when running the view in SQL):

```
ID       Domain
206080   .hello.com
206080   .this.com
206080   www.hello.com
206080   .www.hello.com
206080   .hello.zettaneer.com
```

I see:

```
ID       Domain
206080   .hello.com
206080   .hello.com
206080   .hello.com
206080   .hello.com
206080   .hello.com
```

Using SQL profiler, it seems that the correct query is being executed. For whatever reason however, it brings the incorrect values in .Net.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

---

As requested, This is the code from SQL profiler. Running it directly on the server produces the correct results. :S

```
 SELECT 
 [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
 [Extent1].[Domain] AS [Domain]
 FROM (SELECT 
     [V_eSummary].[ID] AS [ID], 
     [V_eSummary].[Domain] AS [Domain]
     FROM [dbo].[V_eSummary] AS [V_eSummary]) AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Classic asp is **not** ASP.NET.

Comment: How are you viewing the contents of eSummary? Through the debugger, or do you have code iterating through it? If code, can we see the code you're using? No offense, but it seems more likely that your .NET code is wrong than that Linq botched such a simple query.

Comment: Please post the exact SQL code the view is using.

Comment: I think the rest of the .NET code would be useful.

Comment: @AnnL. for the example posted above, I'm using the debugger, but the code I use further down is a for loop:

foreach (var c in eSummary 
{
eModel m = new eModel();
m.ID = c.ID;
m.Domain = c.Domain;
}

Comment: @Oded it's .Net 4 with MVC3 (not classic ASP)

Comment: If you were to put a Debug.WriteLine statement to print out the properties of `c` at the end of each trip through the loop, what would it show?

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to send `eSummary` to an array and see what values you get in the array.

Comment: @AnnL. Output as requested:

ID: 206080
Domain: .hello.com
--------
ID: 206080
Domain: .hello.com
--------
ID: 206080
Domain: .hello.com
--------
ID: 206080
Domain: .hello.com
--------
ID: 206080
Domain: .hello.com
--------

Comment: Then why did you originally tag it with [tag:asp-classic]?

Comment: Interesting.  If you examine ctx.V_eSummary, or loop through it, does it also show the same record repeated over and over?

Comment: That is what seems to be happening.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (as in, I have no hypothesis at the moment, but would like more information), if you do a count on ctx.V_eSummary, and a count on the server of how many records are in the view, do they match?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with .NET. Execute the exact query that you captured in SSMS. The result are likely to be the same.

Be sure to execute this on the right database.

Comment: See above for the query extracted from SQL profiler. The results are most definitely different.

Comment: How would that bug work? We are talking about a normal query executed on a code path that has been war-hardened for 10 years. Unlikely. Can you devise a full executable repro? A small console app with a .sql file that creates the necessary schema? My guess is you will find the bug yourself along the way.